# DataGridView1.CurrentCell and BeginEdit doesn't work if I move with Tab

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, cells

C#, WinForms.

Maybe it's a stupid and trivial problem but I can not get out!
I have a `DataGridView1`with 4 columns. I check if the value of each row, in column 1, is identical to the value of the previous row in column 2. If yes, a `MessageBox` appears to inform me ... and I want to bring the focus to the cell in which there is the double value just entered. I therefore wrote this code:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs cella)
{
    if (cella.RowIndex > 0 && cella.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        var PrevCell = DataGridView1.Rows[cella.RowIndex - 1].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        if (DataGridView1.Rows[cella.RowIndex].Cells[cella.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == PrevCell)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Amount already exists. Change the current value or the previous occurrence", "Double value, already inserted", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows[cella.RowIndex].Cells[cella.ColumnIndex];
            DataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
            //only a test:
            //return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the `CurrentCell` works fine. The problem is that such control is carried out with the `CellEndEdit` Event, when I press the `Tab` key to move to the next cell (or I click with the mouse to the next cell) and therefore, even if the `BeginEdit` placed me on the right cell for let me edit the value, as soon as I press Tab again, it move the changed value in the next cell. It seems that the Tab pressed before displaying the MessageBox remains in memory.

When I'm writing a double value, and MessageBox appears
[image: When I'm writing a double value, and MessageBox appears]

When the CurrentCell and BeginEdit lead me in the correct cell to change the double value
[image: When the CurrentCell and BeginEdit lead me in the correct cell to change the double value]

At the end of the Event

[image: At the end of the Event]

Any idea on how to handle the problem?

Comment: what is the translation of the message box?

Comment: I have translated it only in the MessageBox within the code: `Quantità già presente. Modifica l'attuale valore o l'occorrenza precedente` = `Amount already exists. Change the current value or the previous occurrence` while `Valore doppio, già inserito` = `Double value, already inserted`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to select the cell and call the BeginEdit method *after* the CellEndEdit event happens.  To do that, wrap that code in a BeginInvoke block:

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
  DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows[cella.RowIndex].Cells[cella.ColumnIndex];
  DataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
}));
```

Comment: I never used the `Begin.Invoke` method and the delegate `Action` until now... but I have to study it better because your solution worked! Thanks so much. ;-)